# Как пишутся название учебных заведений

Tags: орфография, ономастика

С большой или с маленькой буквы пишутся названия учебных заведений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В названиях учебных заведений с большой буквы пишется только первое слово.
Пример: *Таврический национальный университет, Российский университет дружбы народов*.
При этом аббривиатура "вуз" пишется строчными буквами.